# Can DataContext.SubmitChanges on a result set created DataContext.ExecuteQuery using joined tables?

Tags: sql, linq, linq-to-sql

I wanted to use Linq to SQL to update some fields in a table, where I needed to join this table to another (to workout some filtering etc).

So, a simple example is as below, noticing the sql run has a join in it

```
public class JoinQueryResults
  {
    [Column(IsPrimaryKey = true)]
    public string MyKey;

    [Column]
    public string Name;

    [Column] 
    public int TotalOrders;

    [Column]
    public string OrdersComment;
  }

  public class MyClass
  {
    public void Update(IDbConnection connection)
    {
      DataContext context = new DataContext(connection);
      const string sql = @"select ord.MyKey, cust.Name, ord.TotalOrders ord.OrdersComment 
                           from Customers cust join Orders ord on cust.MyKey = ord.MyKey";

      var list = context.ExecuteQuery<JoinQueryResults>(sql).ToList();
      foreach (var row in list)
        row.OrdersComment = "Processed";

      var writer = new System.IO.StringWriter();
      context.Log = writer;

      // This does nothing to the underlying data
      context.SubmitChanges();

      // str is emtpy string after the following
      var str = writer.ToString();
    }
  }
```

This all seems to run fine, however when I call context.SubmitChanges() there is no change to the underlying data (in the sql database). I saw in another post to try and use the log writer as above, and the str in my case is empty.

Should this work? Should you be able to update when working with a joined table as above, and if so, what have I done wrong?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0):

You have to mark-up the type the same way any other entity is marked-up. The `Table` attribute seems to be missing.

Comment: Not possible. The "entity" is a mixture of two model classes. There can't be an underlying database table.

Comment: If you don't mark up the entity as a table L2S will not persist changes. If don't want or can't do it my answer is: you are demanding something impossible.

Comment: I agree, I'm not the OP :), it is impossible. The OP should modify `Order` entities.

Comment: Thank you all for your feedback. I thought I would try decorating the entity class with the [Table] attribute, but this caused the result set to be incorrect. So it appear, as mentioned about, we cannot do this where we use a *join* in a query to populate our L2S entity.

Comment: L2S cannot possibly detect that a join was used. Therefore, the join cannot have caused this problem. Something else was.